# Function from `mappend` function to `Monoid` instance?

Tags: haskell, types, metaprogramming

I have a data structure (it's a specific subclass of rose-tree that forms a lattice with greatest-lower bound and lowest-upper bound functions), and it supports two perfectly reasonable functions to serve as the `Monoid` class's `mappend`.

Is there any way to support anonymous `Monoid` instances in haskell? Is this an instance where I should consider using something like Template-Haskell to generate my typeclasses for me?

What I'd love is a `makeMonoid :: (RT a -> RT a -> RT a) -> Monoid a` to let me create the instance on the fly, but I understand that that's incoherent with the stock typesystem as I understand it.
I'm okay with it if I just need to pick a default merge function and write `newtype`s for other merges, just curious

Comment: If you have several instances and don't want to use `newtype`s everywhere you can [pass a "`Monoid`" dictionary around manually](http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/MDCC-TechTalk-Classes-Jim-but-not-as-we-know-them) as `data RTMonoid a = { empty :: RT a, append :: RT a -> RT a -> RT a}` and `rt1 :: RTMonoid a; rt1 = RTMonoid ...`; `rt2 :: RTMonoid a; rt2 = RTMonoid ...`, then you can write your functions to accept an `RTMonoid a` parameter that you use instead.  It's a little clunkier having to pass it around manually, but it makes it more extensible.  If you only have 2 instances, use newtypes.

Comment: You don't *have* to pick a default at all—it may be better to force the user to choose using a newtype. You can also use separate functions to `mergeThisWay` and `mergeThatWay`.

Comment: You might use the typeclasses in http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lattices Personally, I wish lattices were used more frequently in Haskell. They're such a useful structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *can* create "local" instances of `Monoid` on the fly, using the tools in the [reflection](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/reflection) package. There's a [ready-made example](https://github.com/ekmett/reflection/blob/master/examples/Monoid.hs) in the repository. This answer explains it a little.

This is a newtype wrapper over values of type `a`, on which we will define our `Monoid` instance.

```
newtype M a s = M { runM :: a } deriving (Eq,Ord)
```

Notice that there is a phantom type `s` that does not appear in the right hand side. It will carry extra information necessary for the local `Monoid` instance to work.

This is a record whose fields represent the two operation of the `Monoid` class:

```
data Monoid_ a = Monoid_ { mappend_ :: a -> a -> a, mempty_ :: a }
```

The following is the `Monoid` instance definition for `M`:

```
instance Reifies s (Monoid_ a) => Monoid (M a s) where
    mappend a b        = M $ mappend_ (reflect a) (runM a) (runM b)
    mempty = a where a = M $ mempty_ (reflect a)
```

It says: "whenever `s` is a type-level representation of our `Monoid` dictionary `Monoid_`, we can reflect it back to obtain the dictionary, and use the fields to implement the `Monoid` operations for `M`".

Notice that the actual value `a` passed to [`reflect`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/reflection-1.5.1.1/docs/Data-Reflection.html#v:reflect) is not used, it is passed only as a "proxy" of type `M a s` that tells `reflect` which type (`s`) to use to "bring back the record".

The actual local instance is constructed using the [`reify`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/reflection-1.5.1.1/docs/Data-Reflection.html#v:reify) function:

```
withMonoid :: (a -> a -> a) -> a -> (forall s. Reifies s (Monoid_ a) => M a s) -> a
withMonoid f z v = reify (Monoid_ f z) (runM . asProxyOf v)

asProxyOf :: f s -> Proxy s -> f s
asProxyOf a _ = a
```

The `asProxyOf` function is a trick to convince the compiler that the phantom type used in the monoid is the same as the one in the `Proxy` supplied by `reify`.

Comment: An example of how to use `withMonoid` would add greatly to the introductory literature on `Data.Reflection`.

Comment: @Cirdec Another good example would be to  dynamically generate `FromJSON`/`ToJSON` instances for a type, depending on information obtained at runtime. Like, asking the user for a prefix to be added to each field name.